# MVC3 - Is there a single point of entry before the request is routed to a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a method called in MVC3 before request is routed to controller? There are some third party filters which inject data into the request header, and due to some requirements, that will affect the routing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `global.asax` you can implement the following method:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scenes there is a front controller which processes all the requests, analyses a route and directs a request to an appropriate controller. Please refere to the [routing article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)